# Convert Probability Density Function to Normal pdf

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose i have a variable that follows a certain distribution. For example $X \sim exp(\lambda)$. If a want to find $P(X > k)$, i just need to integrate the pdf between $k$ and $\infty$. Suppose that the value i get from the integration is $p$.

Is there a general method to obtain the same value $p$ but integrating between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ a normal pdf with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma$? That is, is there a way to find the parameters mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of a normally distributed random variable $Y$ such that $P(\alpha < Y < \beta) = p$, i.e., the integration of the pdf (eventually multiplied by a constant) gives me the same result? And then, is there a way to do the same but with mean 0 and variance 1? This second steps should be strightforward, starting from another normally distirbuted r.v. (variable subtitution in the integration). If this is not possible in general, are there some distributions for which this operation is possible? If it is not possible, why?

I've heard about gaussianization but i don't know if this is the way to go.

Comment: There are many  many solutions.  Given mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, one is setting $\alpha=-\infty$ and $\beta=\mu +\sigma\, \Phi^{-1}(p)$

Comment: I thought this was essentially a duplicate (in the general case), but I couldn't locate one with a few searches, so I answered, but it's possible this will still close as a duplicate if someone does better on searching than I just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can convert any continuous distribution to a uniform, by transforming it by its cdf.  i.e. if $X\sim F_X$ then $U=F_X(X)$ has a standard uniform distribution.

   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform#Proof

   $\:$
2. You can convert a standard uniform to a standard normal by transforming it by the inverse cdf of the standard normal $Z=\Phi^{-1}(U)$.

   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling#Proof_of_correctness

   $\:$

   So $P(X>k) = P(F_X(X)>F_X(k)) \qquad ( \:=1-F_X(k) \:)\\ \qquad\qquad= P(\Phi^{-1}(F_X(X))>\Phi^{-1}(F_X(k)))\\ \qquad\qquad= P(Z>\Phi^{-1}(F_X(k)))$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you kindly provide a practical example? For instance, if $X \sim exp(\lambda)$, how the standard uniform and then the standard normal will look like?

Comment: I am not clear what you seek when you say "look like". Did you want a picture? Note that there's no closed-form formula for either the function $\Phi$ nor its functional inverse $\Phi^{-1}$.

Comment: You can get information on the standard exponential, the standard uniform and the standard normal all on wikipedia; is there something more specific that you seek?